# Extract all words starting with digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have getting strings like below formats either,

```
"24" // only numbers
"23_hell,23,67,990_test" // number followed by _ followed by string (it repeats with comma)
```

It should not match words that do not start with a digit, like `text`, `abc123`.

I used below regex but it is not working as expected:

```
var val = "23_hell text 23 abc123 45_dell"
val.match(/\d+/g);
```

This will return like this:

```
["23","23","123","45"]
```

but what i need is

```
["23_hell","23","45_dell"]
```

Comment: You probably want `val.match(/\b\d\w*/g)` - extract all words (texts consisting of letters/digits/underscores) starting with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract all words starting with a digit you  may use

```
val.match(/\b\d\w*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNKwdW/1) and a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb%5Cd%5Cw*):

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` -  a word boundary
- `\d` - a digit
- `\w*` - one or more letters, digits or underscores.

JavaScript demo:

```js
var val = "23_hell text 23 abc123 45_dell";
console.log( val.match(/\b\d\w*/g) );
// => ["23_hell", "23", "45_dell"]
```

Comment: Remmember use `//` to comment instead of `#` in js, nice anwser

Comment: @hong4rc I answered a Python question a minute before this one. It was a typo.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I want to get this means "tr,45_tr,tr_45" = > ["tr","45_tr","tr_45"]

Comment: @Harifrais  Then you may simply use `val.match(/\w+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings separate each word using a comma, then use my example below:

```js
var val = "23_hell,23,45_dell";
var newVal = val.split(","); // Returns ["23_hell","23","45_dell"]
```

And get data using:

```js
console.log(newVal[0]); // Logs first value (i.e. "23_hell");
console.log(newVal[1]); // Logs second value (i.e. "23");
console.log(newVal[2]); // Logs second value (i.e. "45_dell");
```